# Understanding anchor_x and anchor_y attributes in Pyglet

Tags: python-2.7, pyglet

I am new to Python and game development and just started learning Pyglet (1.3.2). I am trying to play with labels and their positioning.

I understand that x and y coordinates indicate the pixel position of the labels/images on window. In cases of images or sprints, anchor values determine the position from which the image is anchored to screen (which in turn affects their movement).

However, I do not fully understand the affect of anchor in labels. According to [this](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/text.html) pyglet document, it says:

> The position of the text is given by the x and y coordinates. The
>   meaning of these coordinates is given by the anchor_x and anchor_y
>   parameters.

What kind of meaning is implied here? If they have no movement, shouldn't their position remain fixed irrespective of anchor values?

Additionally, when I run program with these labels:

```
   label1 = pyglet.text.Label('Window1',font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36, x=200, y=100,anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')        
   label2 = pyglet.text.Label('Window2',font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36, x=200, y=100,anchor_x='left', anchor_y='center')
```

It produces output which is again difficult to understand as Window1 (anchor_x='center') is more towards left than Window2 (anchor_x='left'):

[image]

Can someone please elaborate the significance of anchors and how is the final position of label calculated. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty easy. anchor just tells you which part of the label should be positioned at `x` and `y`. `center` means that your labels **center** will be placed on `x` and `y`. and `bottom_left` means your labels **bottom left corner** should be placed at `x` and `y`. In your case, your labels center is placed at `x=200, y=100` when using `center`, that's why the center of your label gets placed aligned with your other labels bottom left corner. See it as a way of telling pyglet/labels what starting position to use, the center of the object or a corner of it.

Comment: @Torxed, that makes sense. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the way anchors work, is that they simply just define the placement point of a object. Meaning, if you have `center` as your anchor, the objects center will be placed at the given coordinate *(in your case, `x=200, y=100`)*

And a bottom left anchor, will tell Pyglet to place the objects bottom left corner at the given position, rather than the center at those coordinates.

If you analyze your own image, this will be quite clear, here the two dots are directly in line with each other:

[image]

They're being positioned at the same coordinate, but because you've re-defined the anchor - it will place the center or a corner at that position.

In red, you've defined `center` as your anchor. And in blue you've defined `bottom left` (default).

*(ignore that the dots aren't perfectly aligned, it was tricky to do on a laptop touch pad while on a rocking train)*

Hopefully this makes sense. Also see my above comment for another way of describing this.

Comment: Yes, I understood this perfectly! Thanks for the efforts :)

Comment: I think I had wrong notions about anchors in image too. Is the concept of anchor in images same as that in labels? 

In images bottom left point is the default anchor. Say x=300 and anchor_x=200. This would mean that difference between bottom-left and x=300 should be 200? 
Additionally, can we change the default anchor position?

Comment: Yes, they're all the same. All objects in Pyglet is based off bottom left anchor - mainly because the positioning starts off in the bottom left corner of the window, so it's natural for all objects to use that as their default anchor. Regarding setting default anchor, yes and no. You need to create your own class which inherits for instance `Label` and your class can set that parameter "by default" every time :)